# Is It Possible To Deploy iOS and Android Applications Using HP Enyo?

Tags: cordova, webos, iphone-web-app, enyo

Today I read this news: [HP ran its webOS SDK on iPad 2, hopes to license it as mobile web app tool](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/08/22/hp_ran_its_webos_sdk_on_ipad_2_hopes_to_license_it_as_mobile_web_app_tool.html) and as soon as I finished reading it and looking at the video I just completely freaked out and this question popped on my head: Is it possible to use the HP Enyo(as it is right now) to deploy native Android and iOS applications using (for example) Phonegap?

I'm already developing Android and iOS applications using Phonegap, but for me the most painful part of the process is to make the UI "beauty" for the OS and some AJAX parts, but the HP Enyo just makes everything so simple, that's why I'm so excited to use it instead of the manner I do the things now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great news: [Enyo 2.0: Open source, and ready for all platforms](http://functionsource.com/post/enyo-2-0-open-source-and-ready-for-all-platforms)

Answer (score 2):

I heard that you can, using PhoneGap: just use your existing Enyo `index.html` file as PhoneGap's `index.html` file.

Comment: I tried Googling to see if anyone managed to make it, but 90% of the results were about a chinese phone and 10% about that article I linked **:/**

Answer (score 2):

Enyo is a regular JavaScript library that runs on any WebKit based browser, so from that point of view there is no reason why you could not create an app with Enyo and package it with phonegap for iOS or Android, assuming you only use the GUI services and none of the Palm specific functions that depend on the hardware (like the function that queries the device orientation).

But you have licensing problem. Enyo is not open source, so you cannot distribute the Enyo framework files with your app, and unlike other JS library, the Enyo files are not hosted anywhere on the net. So in practice, the only devices that you could target legally are those that come with Enyo pre-installed, namely the TouchPad and the Pre3 smartphone.

Comment: The Pre3 won't be released **:(**